# how to call repeatedly a jquery code in easy way?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code and i want to repeat the same process. So what can i do?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".er").unbind('click');
$(".box").delay(1000);
$(".box").animate({width:'400px',height:'200px'},1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the concept of "loops".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this :

Wrap up your code in a function.

Make it run in a timer loop using setInterval.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/furas/2/edit)

Comment: I just face some problem according to your way..... Can you help me plzzzz......?????

Comment: Actually when i use setinterval command then first 3 to 4 times the function running smoothly but after that the process is stucked...